# Filter posts by author selected in page

Tags: pages, query, author

I've inherited a Wordpress project, and my client has a new feature request. For a "portfolio" page template, they want to be able to select an author, which I want to add to the `$args` in my `WP_Query()`. I have no idea where in Wordpress or in my theme-file I would be able to add this option to the page editor... Can anyone set me off in the right direction? Codex isn't helping much.

Comment: Please add more information. What is 'portfolio'? An actual "Page"? A post type? What?

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own query to include or exclude posts from an Author,
 This page has documentation about the options you can pass to a query. http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Author_Parameters

Here is an example to only get posts from the user $author.

```
$author_query = new WP_Query('author_name='.$author);
```

for user 'Amin' : :)

```
$author_query = new WP_Query('author_name=Amin');
```